# Keyboard layout problem during changing persian keyboard

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

the Persian keyboard layout is a little different from the layout we Iranians used to type with, so i tried to edit it. (just want to move some buttons)
(*)i found a way to change it by editing "ir" file in

```
/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols
```

i saved the edited file. after logging out/in, it didn't work and even my persian layout is English right now, so used backup file to restore default setting, or used other persian layout in ubuntu setting. but could'nt make it persian again. you guys can help me?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eGtVK.png)

if you can read persian, [source](https://omigo.ir/post/%D8%AA%D8%BA%DB%8C%DB%8C%D8%B1-%DA%A9%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A7%DA%A9%D8%AA%D8%B1-%DA%A9%D9%84%DB%8C%D8%AF-%D9%87%D8%A7%DB%8C-%DA%A9%DB%8C%D8%A8%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%AF-%D8%AF%D8%B1-%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%86%D9%88%DA%A9%D8%B3-3edd) of *.

edited:
the ir file:

```
// Iranian keyboard layout

////////////////////////////////////////
// Persian layout,
// based on
// Information Technology – Layout of Persian Letters and Symbols on Computer Keyboards
// ISIRI 9147 – 1st Edition
// Institute of Standards and Industrial Research of Iran
// http://www.isiri.org/UserStd/DownloadStd.aspx?id=9147
// http://behnam.esfahbod.info/standards/isiri-keyboard-9147.pdf
//
// Author: Behnam Esfahbod <behnam@esfahbod.info>
//

default  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "pes" {
    name[Group1]= "Persian";

    include "ir(pes_part_basic)"
    include "ir(pes_part_ext)"

    include "nbsp(zwnj2nb3nnb4)"
    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};


partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "pes_keypad" {
    name[Group1]= "Persian (with Persian keypad)";

    include "ir(pes_part_basic)"
    include "ir(pes_part_ext)"
    include "ir(pes_part_keypad)"

    include "nbsp(zwnj2nb3nnb4)"
    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};

hidden partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "pes_part_basic" {

    // Persian digits
    key <AE01> { [ Farsi_1, exclam,     grave           ] };
    key <AE02> { [ Farsi_2, 0x100066c,  at          ] };
    key <AE03> { [ Farsi_3, 0x100066b,  numbersign      ] };
    key <AE04> { [ Farsi_4, 0x100fdfc,  dollar          ] };
    key <AE05> { [ Farsi_5, 0x100066a,  percent         ] };
    key <AE06> { [ Farsi_6, multiply,   asciicircum     ] };
    key <AE07> { [ Farsi_7, Arabic_comma,   ampersand       ] };
    key <AE08> { [ Farsi_8, asterisk,   enfilledcircbullet  ] };
    key <AE09> { [ Farsi_9, parenright, 0x100200e       ] };
    key <AE10> { [ Farsi_0, parenleft,  0x100200f       ] };

    // Persian letters and symbols
    key <AD01> { [ Arabic_dad,      Arabic_fathatan,        degree      ] };
    key <AD02> { [ Arabic_sad,      Arabic_dammatan,    VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AD03> { [ Arabic_theh,     Arabic_kasratan,    0x13a4      ] };
    key <AD04> { [ Arabic_qaf,      Arabic_fathatan,    VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AD05> { [ Arabic_feh,      Arabic_damma,       VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AD06> { [ Arabic_ghain,    Arabic_kasra,       VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AD07> { [ Arabic_ain,      Arabic_commo,       VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AD08> { [ Arabic_heh,      Arabic_shadda,      0x100202d   ] };
    key <AD09> { [ Arabic_khah,     bracketright,       0x100202e   ] };
    key <AD10> { [ Arabic_hah,      bracketleft,        0x100202c   ] };
    key <AD11> { [ Arabic_jeem,     braceright,     0x100202a   ] };
    key <AD12> { [ Arabic_tcheh,    braceleft,      0x100202b   ] };

    key <AC01> { [ Arabic_sheen,    Arabic_fatha,       VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AC02> { [ Arabic_seen, Arabic_damma,       VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AC03> { [ Farsi_yeh,       Arabic_kasra,       Arabic_alefmaksura ] };
    key <AC04> { [ Arabic_beh,      Arabic_hamzaunderalef,  VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AC05> { [ Arabic_lam,      Arabic_hamzaonalef, VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AC06> { [ Arabic_alef,     Arabic_maddaonalef, 0x1000671   ] };
    key <AC07> { [ Arabic_teh,      Arabic_tehmarbuta,  VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AC08> { [ Arabic_noon,     guillemotright,     0x100fd3e   ] };
    key <AC09> { [ Arabic_meem,     guillemotleft,      0x100fd3f   ] };
    key <AC10> { [ Arabic_keheh,    colon,          semicolon   ] };
    key <AC11> { [ Arabic_gaf,      Arabic_semicolon,   quotedbl    ] };

    key <AB01> { [ Arabic_zah,      Arabic_kaf,     VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AB02> { [ Arabic_tah,      0x1000653,      VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AB03> { [ Arabic_zain,     Arabic_jeh,     VoidSymbol  ] };
    key <AB04> { [ Arabic_ra,       Arabic_superscript_alef,0x1000656   ] };
    key <AB05> { [ Arabic_thal,     0x100200c,      0x100200d   ] };
    key <AB06> { [ Arabic_dal,      Arabic_hamza_above, Arabic_hamza_below  ] };
    key <AB07> { [ Arabic_hamzaonyeh    Arabic_hamza,       ellipsis    ] };
    key <AB08> { [ Arabic_waw,      greater,        comma       ] };
    key <AB09> { [ period,      less,           apostrophe  ] };
    key <AB10> { [ Arabic_peh,      Arabic_question_mark,   question    ] };

    key <TLDE> { [ 0x100200d,       division,       asciitilde  ] };
    key <AE11> { [ minus,       Arabic_tatweel,     underscore  ] };
    key <AE12> { [ equal,       plus,           0x1002212   ] };
    key <BKSL> { [ backslash,       bar,            0x1002010   ] };
};

hidden partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "pes_part_ext" {

    // Persian and ASCII digits
    key <AE01> { [ Farsi_1, exclam,     grave,          1   ] };
    key <AE02> { [ Farsi_2, 0x100066c,  at,         2   ] };
    key <AE03> { [ Farsi_3, 0x100066b,  numbersign,     3   ] };
    key <AE04> { [ Farsi_4, 0x100fdfc,  dollar,         4   ] };
    key <AE05> { [ Farsi_5, 0x100066a,  percent,        5   ] };
    key <AE06> { [ Farsi_6, multiply,   asciicircum,        6   ] };
    key <AE07> { [ Farsi_7, Arabic_comma,   ampersand,      7   ] };
    key <AE08> { [ Farsi_8, asterisk,   enfilledcircbullet, 8   ] };
    key <AE09> { [ Farsi_9, parenright, 0x100200e,      9   ] };
    key <AE10> { [ Farsi_0, parenleft,  0x100200f,      0   ] };
};

hidden partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "pes_part_keypad" {

    // Persian digits and Mathematical operators
    key <KPDV> { [ division,    XF86_Ungrab ] };
    key <KPMU> { [ multiply,    XF86_ClearGrab  ] };
    key <KPSU> { [ 0x1002212,   XF86_Prev_VMode ] };
    key <KPAD> { [ plus,    XF86_Next_VMode ] };

    key <KPEN> { [ KP_Enter ] };
    key <KPEQ> { [ equal    ] };

    key <KP7>  { [ KP_Home, Farsi_7 ] };
    key <KP8>  { [ KP_Up,   Farsi_8 ] };
    key <KP9>  { [ KP_Prior,    Farsi_9 ] };

    key <KP4>  { [ KP_Left, Farsi_4 ] };
    key <KP5>  { [ KP_Begin,    Farsi_5 ] };
    key <KP6>  { [ KP_Right,    Farsi_6 ] };

    key <KP1>  { [ KP_End,  Farsi_1 ] };
    key <KP2>  { [ KP_Down, Farsi_2 ] };
    key <KP3>  { [ KP_Next, Farsi_3 ] };

    key <KP0>  { [ KP_Insert,   Farsi_0 ] };
    key <KPDL> { [ KP_Delete,   0x100066b   ] };
};


////////////////////////////////////////
// Kurdish Layout

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "ku" {
    include "tr(ku)"
    name[Group1]= "Kurdish (Iran, Latin Q)";
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "ku_f" {
    include "tr(ku_f)"
    name[Group1]= "Kurdish (Iran, F)";
};

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "ku_alt" {
    include "tr(ku_alt)"
    name[Group1]= "Kurdish (Iran, Latin Alt-Q)";
};

////////////////////////////////////////
// Kurdish Soranî Bahdînî (Arabic) keyboard layout,
// based on the Kurdî Soranî Bahdînî keyboard from KurdITGroup
// which is based on National Iranian Keyboard Standard (ISIRI 2901:1994),
// with additions.
//
// Copyright (C) 2006 Erdal Ronahî, published under the GPL v2
//
// Special copyright note: author explicitly permitted to license this
// layout under MIT/X11 license, for details see
// https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=9541
//
// Author: Erdal Ronahî  <erdal.ronahi@gmail.com>
//
// Kurdish Arabic-Latin Layout for Soranî

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "ku_ara" {
    name[Group1]= "Kurdish (Iran, Arabic-Latin)";

    // Other 3-Level symbols
    key <TLDE> { [ 0x100200d,       division,       asciitilde  ] };
    key <BKSL> { [ backslash,       bar,            ccedilla, Ccedilla  ] };

    // Digits
    key <AE01> { [ 0x1000661,   exclam,     1,  grave       ] };
    key <AE02> { [ 0x1000662,   at,         2,  at      ] };
    key <AE03> { [ 0x1000663,   numbersign, 3,  0x100066b   ] };
    key <AE04> { [ 0x1000664,   dollar,     4,  0x100fdfc   ] };
    key <AE05> { [ 0x1000665,   percent,    5,  0x100066a   ] };
    key <AE06> { [ 0x1000666,   asciicircum,    6,  multiply    ] };
    key <AE07> { [ 0x1000667,   ampersand,  7,  Arabic_comma    ] };
    key <AE08> { [ 0x1000668,   asterisk,   8,  enfilledcircbullet  ] };
    key <AE09> { [ 0x1000669,   parenright, 9,  0x100200e   ] };
    key <AE10> { [ 0x1000660,   parenleft,  0,  0x100200f   ] };
    key <AE11> { [ minus,       Arabic_tatweel,     underscore  ] };
    key <AE12> { [ equal,       plus,           0x1002212   ] };

    key <AD01> { [         Arabic_qaf,            X,  q,  Q ] };
    key <AD02> { [         Arabic_waw,            X,  w,  W ] };
    key <AD03> { [          0x10006d5,   Arabic_heh,  e,  E ] };
    key <AD04> { [         Arabic_ra ,    0x1000695,  r,  R ] };
    key <AD05> { [         Arabic_teh,   Arabic_tah,  t,  T ] };
    key <AD06> { [          0x10006cc,    0x10006ce,  y,  Y ] };
    key <AD07> { [  Arabic_hamzaonyeh, Arabic_hamza,  u,  U ] };
    key <AD08> { [         Arabic_hah,   Arabic_ain,  i,  I ] };
    key <AD09> { [          0x10006c6, Arabic_hamzaonwaw,  o,  O ] };
    key <AD10> { [          0x100067e,  Arabic_theh,  p,  P ] };
    key <AD11> { [ bracketright,    braceright, ucircumflex, Ucircumflex    ] };
    key <AD12> { [ bracketleft,     braceleft,  scedilla, Scedilla  ] };

    key <AC01> { [ Arabic_alef, Arabic_maddaonalef, a, A    ] };
    key <AC02> { [ Arabic_seen,     Arabic_sheen,   s, S    ] };
    key <AC03> { [  Arabic_dal,     Arabic_thal,    d, D    ] };
    key <AC04> { [  Arabic_feh, Arabic_hamzaunderalef,  f, F    ] };
    key <AC05> { [   0x10006af,     Arabic_ghain,   g, G    ] };
    key <AC06> { [  Arabic_heh,     0x100200c,  h, H    ] };
    key <AC07> { [   0x1000698, Arabic_hamzaonalef, j, J    ] };
    key <AC08> { [   0x10006a9,     Arabic_kaf, k, K    ] };
    key <AC09> { [  Arabic_lam,     0x10006b5,  l, L    ] };
    key <AC10> { [  Arabic_semicolon,   colon,      ecircumflex, Ecircumflex    ] };
    key <AC11> { [  apostrophe,     quotedbl,   icircumflex, Icircumflex    ] };

    key <AB01> { [ Arabic_zain,     Arabic_dad, z, Z    ] };
    key <AB02> { [ Arabic_khah,     Arabic_sad, x, X    ] };
    key <AB03> { [ Arabic_jeem,     0x1000686,  c, C    ] };
    key <AB04> { [   0x10006a4,     Arabic_zah, v, V    ] };
    key <AB05> { [ Arabic_beh,      0x1000649,  b, B    ] };
    key <AB06> { [ Arabic_noon, Arabic_tehmarbuta,  n, N    ] };
    key <AB07> { [ Arabic_meem, Arabic_tatweel,     m, M    ] };
    key <AB08> { [ Arabic_comma,    greater,    comma       ] };
    key <AB09> { [ period,      less,       apostrophe  ] };
    key <AB10> { [ slash,       Arabic_question_mark,   question    ] };

    include "nbsp(zwnj2nb3)"
    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};

// EXTRAS:

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated keyboard layout file with the Keyboard Layout Editor.
// For more about the software, see http://code.google.com/p/keyboardlayouteditor
//
// Version 0.2, fixed AD09.
//
// Layout by Ernst Tremel, http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=9365469&postcount=32
// Creation of this file by Simos Xenitellis.

partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "ave"
{
    name[Group1] = "Avestan";

    key <AB01> { [ U10B30,         U10B32 ] }; //  
    key <AB02> { [ U10B11,         U10B12 ] }; //  
    key <AB03> { [ U10B17,          UE102 ] }; //  
    key <AB04> { [ U10B2C,         U10B13 ] }; //  
    key <AB05> { [ U10B20,         U10B21 ] }; //  
    key <AB06> { [ U10B25,         U10B27 ] }; //  
    key <AB07> { [ U10B28,         U10B29 ] }; //  
    key <AB08> { [ U10B3C,         U10B39 ] }; //  
    key <AB09> { [ U10B3E,         U10B3D ] }; //  
    key <AB10> { [ U10B3F, periodcentered ] }; //  ·

    key <AC01> { [ U10B00,         U10B01 ] }; //  
    key <AC02> { [ U10B2F,         U10B31 ] }; //  
    key <AC03> { [ U10B1B,         U10B1C ] }; //  
    key <AC04> { [ U10B1F,         U10B16 ] }; //  
    key <AC05> { [ U10B14,         U10B15 ] }; //  
    key <AC06> { [ U10B35,          UE100 ] }; //  
    key <AC07> { [ U10B18,         U10B24 ] }; //  
    key <AC08> { [ U10B10,          UE101 ] }; //  
    key <AC09> { [ U10B2E,          UE103 ] }; //  
    key <AC10> { [ U10B3B,         U10B3A ] }; //  
    key <AC11> { [ U10B1D                 ] }; // 

    key <AD01> { [ U10B22,         U10B23 ] }; //  
    key <AD02> { [ U10B33,         U10B34 ] }; //  
    key <AD03> { [ U10B08,         U10B09 ] }; //  
    key <AD04> { [ U10B2D,         U10B26 ] }; //  
    key <AD05> { [ U10B19,         U10B1A ] }; //  
    key <AD06> { [ U10B2B,         U10B2A ] }; //  
    key <AD07> { [ U10B0E,         U10B0F ] }; //  
    key <AD08> { [ U10B0C,         U10B0D ] }; //  
    key <AD09> { [ U10B0A,         U10B0B ] }; //  
    key <AD10> { [ U10B1E                 ] }; // 
    key <AD11> { [ U10B06,         U10B07 ] }; //  
    key <AD12> { [ U10B02,         U10B03 ] }; //  

    key <AE01> { [ U10B78                 ] }; // 
    key <AE02> { [ U10B79                 ] }; // 
    key <AE03> { [ U10B7A                 ] }; // 
    key <AE04> { [ U10B7B                 ] }; // 
    key <AE05> { [ U10B7C                 ] }; // 
    key <AE06> { [ U10B7D                 ] }; // 
    key <AE07> { [ U10B7E                 ] }; // 
    key <AE08> { [ U10B7F                 ] }; // 

    key <BKSL> { [ U10B04,         U10B05 ] }; //  
    key <LSGT> { [ U10B04,         U10B05 ] }; //  
};
```

Comment: I can't see any obvious mistakes with your edits, so the problem seems not to be due to those. Did you reboot after having restored the original symbols file?

Comment: yes i did, this is not the edited one, this is the backup i got and restore

Comment: Really? I compared it with the `ir` file on my system, and noticed a bunch of changes. Assumed those were your edits...

Comment: Can you send me the codes to replace them with mine? maybe i didn't copy some lines...

Comment: I see no reason to send anything. If you are not sure that you restored the original version, you can simply reinstall the package: `sudo apt install --reinstall xkb-data`

Comment: thank you but i got the code from another computer and kind of restore it again, worked! Dametgarm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just didn't restore the codes completely.
got them from another computer.
now I can type سلام داداش‌ :)